# Display the data in pie Chart - LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforce-id, report-chart, chartjs

Trying to display the data in Chart.

First trying with some hardcoded values to display the data in Pie/bar chart.

The view of the Chart is Fullscreen, trying to accomplish in small Place. 
Removed width and height in `canvas` tag still it's showing in full screen.

Checked in my inspect element, when i load the chart `style="width: 1869px; height: 934px;"` following style has been added.

[image]

[image]

**HTML**

```
 <div class="slds-box slds-theme_default custom-background">
            <!-- <canvas width="400" height="400" lwc:dom="manual"></canvas> -->
            <canvas lwc:dom="manual"></canvas>
        </div>
```

**JS**

```
chartJSLoaded;
  chart;

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.chartJSLoaded = false;
  }

  renderedCallback() {
    // alert("rendered");
    if (!this.chartJSLoaded) {
      // alert("chartJSLoaded" + this.chartJSLoaded);
      loadScript(this, ChartJS)
        .then(() => {
          this.chartJSLoaded = true;

          this.buildChart();
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          this.dispatchEvent(
            new ShowToastEvent({
              title: "Error Loading Chart JS",
              message: error.message,
              variant: "error"
            })
          );          
        });
    }
  }

  buildChart() {
    let canvas = this.template.querySelector("canvas");
    let context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    this.chart = new window.Chart(context, {
      type: "bar",
      data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "# of Votes",
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
              "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
              "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",
              "rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)",
              "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)",
              "rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)",
              "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)"
            ],
            borderColor: [
              "rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)",
              "rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)",
              "rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)",
              "rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)",
              "rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)",
              "rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)"
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
          }
        ]
      },
      options: {
        legend: {
          position: "top",
          padding: 10
        },
        scales: {
          xAxes: [
            {
              beginAtZero: true,
              ticks: {
                autoSkip: false
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        responsive: true
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: This really does not fit the SFSE format. Please start an implementation and post when you're able to articulate a specific, detailed question ([ask]).

Comment: @DavidReed I have edited my question

Comment: @SFDC_Beginner did you try wrapping it in another div with height and width?

Comment: Tried this working fine. `<div class="slds-box slds-theme_default custom-background"
            style="position: relative; height:40vh; width:40vw">
            <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
        </div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried by adding another `div` on top of the div, Solved the issue.

```
<div class="slds-box slds-theme_default custom-background" style="position: relative; height:40vh; width:40vw"> 
      <div class="slds-box slds-theme_default custom-background">
            <canvas lwc:dom="manual"></canvas>
        </div>
</div>
```